# Javascript toFixed() no funciona

Tags: javascript

La verdad es que no entiendo esto

```js
var movementQuotient = 3

function cutDecimal(x) {
  return Number.parseFloat(x).toFixed(2);
}

console.log(cutDecimal(movementQuotient))
```

Al ejecutar estas lineas el output es el esperado: 3.00

Pero al hacer esto, que tecnicamente es lo mismo

```js
var movementQuotient = 3

function cutDecimal(x) {
  return Number.parseFloat(x).toFixed(2);
}

cutDecimal(movementQuotient)

console.log(movementQuotient)
```

Por que ocurre esto? La funcion toFixed() me esta dando muchisimos problemas como este

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es que el segundo código no es lo mismo que el primero. En el primero envías a la consola el valor que devuelve la función **cutDecimal**, mientras que en el segundo caso lo que estás enviando es el valor de la variable **movementQuotient** que, evidentemente es 3. Otra cosa sería si asignaras a una variable el resultado de llamar a la función y enviaras a la consola ese resultado

```
qd = cutDecimal(movementQuotient)

console.log(qd)
```

Comment: exacto, `cutDecimal` no modifica el valor que le envías (en este caso la variable `movementQuotient`), sino que retorna el nuevo valor modificado... debes asignar ese resultado a una variable o mostrarlo directamente como indica Pedro Gonzales en esta respuesta.